# react-redux-firebase (firestoreConnect) Comparison Queries not working

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I'm trying to query data from Firestore database using **react-redux-firebase** `firestoreConnect` method as follows.

```
const myFirebaseFirestoreTimestampFromDate = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(1552053086000))


export default compose(
connect(mapStateToProps),
firestoreConnect( props =>
    {
        const {single_class, index} = props; 


        return [
            {    
                collection : 'StudentScanClass',
                where: [
                    ['unitcode', '==', props.single_class.unitcode],
                    ['course', '==', props.single_class.courses[props.index].course],
                    ["date", "<=", myFirebaseFirestoreTimestampFromDate],
                    ['yearofstudy', '==', props.single_class.courses[props.index].yearofstudy.toString()],
                ],

            }  
            ]          
    }
)

) (AttendCourses);
```

So my problem is:

This is working

```
["date", "==", myFirebaseFirestoreTimestampFromDate],
```

While this is not working

```
["date", "<=", myFirebaseFirestoreTimestampFromDate],
```

Neither this

```
["date", ">=", myFirebaseFirestoreTimestampFromDate],
```

Someone help me out, What might the problem be with the less and greater than queries?

**Note** : The date field is a Timestamp field.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I was able to achieve this through [Firebase Query Indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) . Otherwise all the queries work just fine.